# seeing null's even after using coalesce in hive

Tags: hive, null, hiveql

I am getting null values in the target table even after using

```
coalesce(x.coulmn, 0)
```

while loading the data. column is a `smallint` data type. Please let me know if anyone has faced this type of issue.

```
coalesce(cntdim.epsd_ind, 0) as epsd_ind
```

this should return 0 or 1 but i am getting null in the target.

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Have faced the same issue when input data cannot be converted to the target data type.
When it cannot be converted, Hive silently converts it to NULL during insert. To avoid this apply explicit conversion using cast():

```
coalesce(cast(x.coulmn as smallint), 0)
```

In this case if value cannot be converted to `smallint`, cast will return `NULL`, `coalesce` will return `0`. Or use other means to make sure you are inserting compatible or the same data type exactly.

Without `cast()` if `x.column` is not null and cannot be converted to smallint, `coalesce` will return value, and value will be inserted as NULL:

```
coalesce(x.coulmn, 0)
```

Similar issue can be observed when you inserting strings into DATE column. If string is in a wrong format, like `'2017-01-010000'` it will be converted to NULL without exception. And interestingly, `bigint` being inserted into `int` in Hive 1.2.x is truncated to fit int, not converted to null.

Comment: hey @leftjoin thanks for the input but the source and the target are of same datatype in my case

Comment: @2strange: Its not about datatypes that you defined in both the tables...if your actual data is not of the expected type(smallint in this case), then hive would show you null. To avoid it, you may use the above suggestion